# React store session

Tags: reactjs, session, authentication

i log in to my backend via react by this code:

```
export function PostData(type, userData) {

let BaseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', userData.username);
formData.append('password', userData.password);

fetch(BaseUrl + type, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson);
  resolve(responseJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
  reject(error);
});
```

});
}

next i want to fetch data from other url by this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Datas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/', {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(response => { return response.json() })
      .then(results => this.setState({
        tasks: results,
        isLoading: false
      }));

  }
  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
        <div classname="App">

          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
                <li key="{item.id}">
                  Name: {item.name} | Email: {item.description}
                </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Datas;
```

but i got error 401: Unauthorized, so my question is how can i fetch data, should i store session in some way? I thought that if i log in to my backend app and i got message with status 200, default i can do request which i want.
Please about help/hints

Spring Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  private MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler mySuccessHandler;

  private SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler myFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
  }

  @Override
  protected MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleSocialUserDetailsService simpleSocialUserDetailsService() {
    return new SimpleSocialUserDetailsService(userRepository);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
          .cors()
        .and()
          .csrf().disable()
          .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*", "/success*").anonymous()
          .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/signup/**", "/css/*", "/webjars/**","/js/*","/image/*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .formLogin()
          .successHandler(mySuccessHandler)
          .failureHandler(myFailureHandler)
          .loginProcessingUrl("perform_login")
//          .successForwardUrl("/tasks")
        .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll()
        .and()
          .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
  }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
        "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your frontend (react) looks Ok The issue is with the backend, which we can't see.

Comment: i updated my question about spring config

Comment: My bad, the problem is in your frontend. In your second fetch, you are missing the credentials, which are name and password in your form data.

This is usually done by creating a session.

Answer (score 0):

Your **/login** endpoint is anonymous, meaning it doesn't require any authentication before trying to access it, it just expects some data (credentials) and returns you something (potentially a auth token). You then can store that token (**localStorage**) and pass it in headers as **'Authorization: '(Bearer/Basic) _YOUR_TOKEN_'** with your API calls.

EDIT:

If you get a token after login, you can do something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('__MY_TOKEN__', response.data.access_token)
```

then create a helper function to fetch and automatically inject the headers for you:

```
 function apiCall(url, method = 'GET', body) {
    return fetch(url, {
       method,
       body,
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('__MY_TOKEN__')
      }
    })
 }
```

then instead of **fetch(...).then(...)** you can use **apiCall('http://localhost:8080/api/tasks').then(...)**

The Authorisation type and content depends on your backend. My solution is based on the assumption that you receive back an access token.

Comment: Hmm, so i should create new state which will hold session storage and pass it for every time if i call api rest?

Comment: Not a new state (if you mean the React component state), the session usually stays in localStorage (because you still want to keep if if your refresh the page). You can create a helper function that wraps fetch and passes the Authorization headers for you so you don't have to do it every time manually.

Comment: Ok i see, i must read something about localStorage :) thank you for help

Comment: I just edited my answer with a quick and simple idea of how it would look, but again it depends on your app and needs.

Comment: Ok, but how can i get __MY_TOKEN__ ? Is it a special variable?

Comment: No, you can name it anything :) that would be the access token you receive back from the backend (if you do)

Comment: Aa ok, i will try and let you know :)

Comment: But for function localStorage.setItem i need 2 parameters, variable and string, what is variable in this case?

Comment: It doesn't work yet, what is 'Authorization': 'Bearer ? Maybe my backend doesn't handle it?

Comment: Check the last paragraph of my answer :) you have Authorization headers in the allow list so I’m assuming that’s what you use. This is not a plug and play solution.